# mysql master slave replcation Error 1045

Tags: mysql

```
*********************** 1. row ************************
           Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
              Master_Host: x.x.x.x.
              Master_User: slave
              Master_Port: 3306
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 2190425
           Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000002
            Relay_Log_Pos: 4
    Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
         Slave_IO_Running: No
        Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
          Replicate_Do_DB:
      Replicate_Ignore_DB:
       Replicate_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Ignore_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
               Last_Errno: 0
               Last_Error:
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 2190425
          Relay_Log_Space: 106
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File:
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
       Master_SSL_CA_File:
       Master_SSL_CA_Path:
          Master_SSL_Cert:
        Master_SSL_Cipher:
           Master_SSL_Key:
    Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
            Last_IO_Errno: 1045
            Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'slave@x.x.x.x:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
           Last_SQL_Errno: 0
           Last_SQL_Error:
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:

```
No query specified
```

Comment: Please describe the slave's login. Did you grant its user the `replication` privilege on the master? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto-repuser.html

Comment: yes i did .. actually i m able to login with this slave user thru Putty on Slave server...

Answer (score 0):

Hunted high and low with an identical problem, turns out you cannot use a pound sign ‘#’ when your password is in my.cnf either. A work around is to copy the password into your master.info file.